# How can I pass my list of URLs as parameters to the requests.get() function?(python)

Tags: python, list, web, web-scraping, python-requests

JSON file like this

```
{"ip":[{
  "urllist":{
             "url1", 
             "url2", 
             "url3"
             }
          }
       ]}
```

I have a list like this .I got this list by parsing the JSON file

```
urls = [{'url1', 'url2', 'url3',...}]
```

i cant handle this problem with

```py
for url in urls:
    url = requests.get(url)
```

i add full code ;I mentioned the JSON file content above

```py
TEMPLATE: str = """
{}
"""
LAST = dict()
ip_address: List[str] = list()
def crop_list(_list: List[Any]):
    global LAST
    try:
       idx = _list.index(LAST)
       return _list[idx:]
    except ValueError:
       return _list
def parse_ip():
   data = crop_list(jsonData["ip"])
    for item in data:
        txt = item["urllist"]
        ip_address.append(TEMPLATE.format(txt))
    for url in ip_address:
        resp = requests.get(url)
```

Comment: Could you share your error?

Comment: If you could parse your JSON file into a variable `tmp`, you could merely use: `tmp['ip'][0]['urllist']` to get `{'url1', 'url2', 'url3',...}` and you can use your for loop as you have described.

Comment: try it with nested loops, you are iterating through the urls(list), url will be a set...so iterate also through the set

Comment: 'raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url))
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for' my url list @Gabip

Answer (score 2):

The urls aren't elements in `urls` list but are part of a set, which is the only element in your `urls` list. You should change your code to:

```
for url in urls[0]:
    res = requests.get(url)
```

According to your last edit, if `ip_address` meant to be the list of your urls, you should do the following:

```
ip_address: List[str] = list()
def parse_ip():
   data = crop_list(jsonData["ip"])
    for item in data:
        urls = list(item["urllist"])
        ip_address.extend(urls)
    for url in ip_address:
        resp = requests.get(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for url in data['ip'][0]['urllist']:
    print(url)
```

Output:

```
url1
url3
url2
```